# SQL Server Joining Between Two Tables Based on Closest Value

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two sets of data, as shown below. 
Table 1:

```
enter code here 
ID     Value_1
1      233.67
2      83.28
3      84.49
4      1234.83
```

Table 2:

```
NewID  Value_3     Value_4
5      NULL        83
6      NULL        85
7      NULL        235
```

I want to join the two tables in such a way that the resulting data set would look like below.

```
ID     NewID     Value_1     Value_2
1      7         233.67      235
2      5         83.28       83
3      6         84.49       85
4      NULL      1234.83     NULL
```

I know that using the ROUND command would cause future problems. Do any of you know how I could create the above resulting set?

Comment: Why does ID 4 not have a match? The "nearest" value would seem to be 235 to me. There are some rules not yet shared here. It would be very helpful if you could post create table statements and insert statements for your two tables so we don't have to.

Comment: Agree with the comment above. Closest is a very vague term. Please define the rules a little better if possible.

Comment: Essentially, I want to create a one-to-one match between the two tables, where one value in the first table only matches with 1 value in the second table. Therefore, if one table has 4 entries and the other table has 3 entries, then there should only be 3 matches. Additionally, closest means that the difference between one value in the first table is minimized with one value in the second table (the sign of the difference makes no difference to me. The absolute value is what is important).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    Id int,
    Value1 float
)
INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
(1,      233.67),
(2,      83.28),
(3,      84.49),
(4,      1234.83)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    NewId int,
    Value2 float
)

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES
(5,     83),
(6,     85),
(7,    235)

SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.Id,
    FIRST_VALUE(t2.NewId) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id ORDER BY ABS(t1.Value1 - t2.Value2) ASC) AS NewId,
    t1.Value1,
    FIRST_VALUE(t2.Value2) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id ORDER BY ABS(t1.Value1 - t2.Value2) ASC) AS Value2
FROM @Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN @Table2 t2
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

But you will get a result for ID=4 too.

Answer (score 0):

This approach avoids a cross join, which requires every combination to be tested.  It also works with SQL Server 2005 and up. It works by calculating a lower and upper bound between the midpoints of each record in `Table2` and then joining on `Table1` where `Value_1` is between the midpoints.  If `Value_1` lands right on the boundary this code will round up (choose the higher of `Value_4` to match).

```
--Load Table1
select 1 ID, convert(float,233.67) Value_1 into #Table1
insert into #Table1 select 2, 83.28
insert into #Table1 select 3, 84.49
insert into #Table1 select 4, 1234.83

--Load Table2
select 5 NewID, null Value_3, convert(float,83) Value_4 into #Table2
insert into #Table2 select 6, NULL, 85
insert into #Table2 select 7, NULL, 235

;with cte_Table2 as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value_4) OrderNum
from #Table2
)
Select #Table1.ID, 
    NewTable2.NewID, 
    #Table1.Value_1,
    NewTable2.Value_4 Value_2
from #Table1
full join
    (
    select Table2.NewID, 
        Table2.Value_3, 
        Table2.Value_4, 
        Table2Prev.Value_4 + (Table2.Value_4 - Table2Prev.Value_4) / 2.0 LowerBound, 
        Table2.Value_4 + (Table2Next.Value_4 - Table2.Value_4) / 2.0 UpperBound
    from cte_Table2 Table2
    left join cte_Table2 Table2Prev
    on Table2.OrderNum = Table2Prev.OrderNum + 1
    left join cte_Table2 Table2Next
    on Table2.OrderNum = Table2Next.OrderNum - 1
    ) NewTable2
on (#Table1.Value_1 < UpperBound or UpperBound is null)
    and (#Table1.Value_1 >= LowerBound or LowerBound is null)
order by 1
```

I noticed that you did not show a match for `ID` of 4 in your expected output.  If you need some kind of range to exclude matches then you would have to add that restriction to the `ON` conditions of the join.  For example you could exclude values that are outside a threshold of 10 by making sure you use a `FULL JOIN` and add this to the ON conditions:

```
and abs(#Table1.Value_1-NewTable2.Value_4) < 10.0
```

It occurs to me though that maybe what you are really trying to do is a type of join where not only is the value in `Table1` matched with it's closest value in `Table2` but the value in `Table2` is **also** the closest value in `Table1`.  In this case, you would have to build a sub-query for `Table1` with the boundary conditions and then check for it's closest match as well.  Like this:

```
;with cte_Table1 as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value_1) OrderNum
from #Table1
), 
cte_Table2 as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value_4) OrderNum
from #Table2
)
Select NewTable1.ID, 
    NewTable2.NewID, 
    NewTable1.Value_1,
    NewTable2.Value_4 Value_2
from
    (
    select Table1.ID,
        Table1.Value_1, 
        Table1Prev.Value_1 + (Table1.Value_1 - Table1Prev.Value_1) / 2.0 LowerBound, 
        Table1.Value_1 + (Table1Next.Value_1 - Table1.Value_1) / 2.0 UpperBound
    from cte_Table1 Table1
    left join cte_Table1 Table1Prev
    on Table1.OrderNum = Table1Prev.OrderNum + 1
    left join cte_Table1 Table1Next
    on Table1.OrderNum = Table1Next.OrderNum - 1
    ) NewTable1
full join
    (
    select Table2.NewID, 
        Table2.Value_3, 
        Table2.Value_4, 
        Table2Prev.Value_4 + (Table2.Value_4 - Table2Prev.Value_4) / 2.0 LowerBound, 
        Table2.Value_4 + (Table2Next.Value_4 - Table2.Value_4) / 2.0 UpperBound
    from cte_Table2 Table2
    left join cte_Table2 Table2Prev
    on Table2.OrderNum = Table2Prev.OrderNum + 1
    left join cte_Table2 Table2Next
    on Table2.OrderNum = Table2Next.OrderNum - 1
    ) NewTable2
on (NewTable1.Value_1 < NewTable2.UpperBound or NewTable2.UpperBound is null)
    and (NewTable1.Value_1 >= NewTable2.LowerBound or NewTable2.LowerBound is null)
    and (NewTable2.Value_4 < NewTable1.UpperBound or NewTable1.UpperBound is null)
    and (NewTable2.Value_4 >= NewTable1.LowerBound or NewTable1.LowerBound is null)
order by 1
```

Now the records in the tables will only match if the values are the closest match both ways.  This will ensure that each record in `Table1` will be matched to at most 1 value in `Table2`.  Because it's a full join you can get null values on either side... depending on which table is smaller.

One more thing to mention... this code might not handle duplicate values the way you need.  If you have more than one of the same value in either `Value_1` or `Value_4`, it will find a match to one of them but not both.  If you want that... then you would have to change your common table expressions to:

```
;with cte_Table1 as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value_1) OrderNum
from (select distinct Value_1 from #Table1) tbl1
), 
cte_Table2 as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value_4) OrderNum
from (select distinct Value_4 from #Table2) tbl2
)
```

Then update your sub-queries to only output the values with the boundaries.  This would give you best matches with between the unique values.  Then you could join to `Table1` and `Table2` ON `Table1.Value_1 = NewTable1.Value1 and Table2.Value_4 = NewTable2.Value_4` to get the rest of the fields.

Certainly some optimizations can be made if you have very large tables... like breaking out some of these sub-queries into indexed temporary tables.